# prompt for a value on grunt devtools

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools, prompt

I am trying to use the prompt plugin https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt on devtools plugin for google chrome, has anybody tried to use this plugin? is basically a grunt interface for your developer window in chrome is really useful for us but it doesn't support custom prompt so every task has to be run without custom arguments and be created with the arguments already defined this way:

```
grunt.registerTask('mytask:foo', 'Watch out for foos', function(param) {
    if (param.length == 0) {
        grunt.fatal('Foo Watch failed!');
    }

    grunt.config.set('pram1', param);
    grunt.task.run('mytask1');
});
```

instead of the normal `mytask` definition, without `:foo`. Has anybody managed to create a prompt on the dev window? thanks.